# reCAPTCHA not stopping users logging in

Tags: python, html, django, recaptcha

I am trying to use Google reCAPTCHA for my login form to prevent spam. After following the necessary steps to get it all working, users can still login. They can fill out there details and login with out ticking the checkbox which isn't correct.

I think it might be the placement in the DOM so I tried moving it around and that didn't work.

CODE:

````
{% extends 'public/base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block head %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "public/css/auth.css" %}" />
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container mt-5 mb-5 login-container">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group mt-4">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Log In</legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
                <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="################################
                "></div>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Login</button>
                <small class="text-muted ml-2">
                    <a href="{% url 'password_reset' %}">Forgot Password?</a>
                </small>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="border-top pt-3 mb-4">
            <small class="text-muted">
                Need An Account? <a class="ml-2" href="{% url 'register' %}">Sign Up Now</a>
            </small>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}```

Thanks.
````

Comment: How are you checking that the recaptcha is valid in the view/form?

Answer (score 0):

When you use the captcha, a textarea is added dynamically inside `<div class="g-recaptcha">`.
That textarea is not visible and by default has `id="g-recaptcha-response"`.

You can get it with:

```
document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').value
```

In your login form you have to check if that textarea has a value or not. If it has a value then user has used successfully the captcha and can continue with the login process.

Something like this:

```
<form onsubmit="return check_form()">
...
</form>

<script>
function check_form()
{
   return document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').value != '';
}
</script>
```

If `check_form()` returns FALSE, then the form is not submitted.